# Android Tesseract App crashes on OCR Function

Tags: android, android-ndk, tesseract, tess-two

I am trying to implement Tesseract into my android project but am getting a crash when trying to complete the OCR.

Here is how I'm setting up Tesseract:

```
 TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.setDebug(true);
        baseApi.init(imagePath, "eng");
        baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
        baseApi.end();
```

This is how I'm setting up the image information to pass into the TesseractAPI:

```
        destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), name + ".png");

        imagePath = destination.getAbsolutePath();

        String name =   dateToString(new Date(),"yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss");
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
10734-10734/www.rshdev.com.ocr E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: www.rshdev.com.ocr, PID: 10734
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/www.rshdev.com.ocr-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libpngt.so"
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
            at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:43)
            at www.rshdev.com.ocr.MainActivity.ocr(MainActivity.java:140)
            at www.rshdev.com.ocr.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:86)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3570)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3617)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1352)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: according to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/nQobKd2Gl_8/Z5yWAvCh4h4J if you're using Android Studio, you need to put the .so file in src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/

Comment: Did you follow the [build instructions for the OCR engine](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#building), and did you get `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` at the last step of the build process?

Comment: I followed all of the steps. once I reached the step: ndk-build it states command not found. I dont know how to move forward.

Comment: You have to install the NDK and add its directory to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to comment back, been out of the office. SO I was able to get the  `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` to happen but now I am at the next part. I install the language pack, file named: eng.traineddata. But, I am not sure what I need to put inside the `baseApi.init("/mnt/sdcard/tesseract/", "eng");` portion of running the code. Thanks for everyones help so far, and again sorry for taking so long to respond.

Comment: Hi ScottMobile, I am getting the same issue.How to resolve the issue?.Please help me ASAP.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tesseract does not crash in the OCR function, it crashes trying to load a library:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ... couldn't find "libpngt.so"
...
at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:43)
```

But line 43 in the source that I have reads:

```
    System.loadLibrary("tess");
```

therefore it tries to load *libtess.so* but reports a failure on *libpngt.so*.

Either:

1) your source code of TessBaseAPI.java is different, it contains `System.loadLibrary("pngt");` and that library is missing. Make sure the .apk contains it. Eclipse used to have a misfeature: if your code depends on a library, you configure that dependency for compilation in one place and for delivery in another place. And IIRC .so dependency was specified in a 3rd place.

2) libtess.so is compiled with dynamic linking (try to use static linking then)

3) you are trying to run it in the emulator (try on a real device then).

This is all what can be said from the information you provided.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to comment back, been out of the office. Thank you for the response, I was able to get the issue fixed. I did not properly build the NDK .But, I am at the next part. I install the language pack, file named: eng.traineddata. But, I am not sure what I need to put inside the `baseApi.init("/mnt/sdcard/tesseract/", "eng");` portion of running the code. Thanks for everyones help so far, and again sorry for taking so long to respond.

Answer (score 0):

More info about solution:

I faced with this issue when I moved from Windows to Linux. My Linux had no **NDK** installed.

I've downloaded it from [official source](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/ndk/downloads/index.html#download).

Instructions for installing under Linux:

Go to the directory where you downloaded it.
Execute the package. For example:

```
ndk$ chmod a+x android-ndk-r10c-darwin-x86_64.bin
ndk$ ./android-ndk-r10c-darwin-x86_64.bin
```

**You also need to rebuild tess-two under Linux. Follow the instruction in oficial** [source](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the same gradle version on your project and in the tess lib project. Example:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    }
}
```

The value on *classpath* must be equals on both projects.

Answer (score 0):

1. do not update any gradle aur sdk update... i repeat ..do ignore all
   the update if asking and it will work smoothly.  Just import the
   project of priyankverma######## from github and IGNORE all the
   updates ... i am sure you wont get this libpngt.so error.

   1. Download or clone the project
   2. import in android studio
   3. let the gradle and sdk versions as it is and
   4. IGNORE all the UPDATES even it is saying "Strongly Recommended.
   5. simply run the project. :)