# Android OCR: Application crashes at OCR function(or trying to load library)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, tesseract, crashlytics

I am student currently working on an OCR function for android on Android Studio 1.5.

I have found many great examples online and have been trying to implement it on Android Studio. I have already configured the NDK build and the application is able to run on Eclipse(juno) and Android Studio.

The codes I have can be found here: https://github.com/TheWall89/AndrOCR

However on Android Studio, the application crashes whenever I reach the OCR function of the app.

I have researched online and implemented Crashlytics in my codes to find out the cause of the crash.

Below are the output shown in Crashlytics:

[image]

[image]

Following are the raw code output of Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4237)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5181)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20887)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4232)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5181)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20887)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
Caused by java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.matpergo.androcr-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.matpergo.androcr-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libpngt.so"
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
       at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(TessBaseAPI.java:43)
       at com.matpergo.androcr.ShowImage.initTess(ShowImage.java:187)
       at com.matpergo.androcr.ShowImage$OCR.onPreExecute(ShowImage.java:567)
       at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
       at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
       at com.matpergo.androcr.ShowImage.startOCR(ShowImage.java:204)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4232)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5181)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20887)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
```

As pointed out by the output, I assume that the error is caused by InvocationTargetException and UnsatisfiedLinkError error.

I have searched online for the related solutions; for UnsatisfiedLinkError error; suggestions are that the application did not fail at the OCR function, but fails to load the library([Android Tesseract App crashes on OCR Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706640/android-tesseract-app-crashes-on-ocr-function)).

However, I failed to implement the solution as specified and could not get my application to work appropriately.

Any suggestions/solutions will be greatly appreciated ~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UnsatisfiedLinkError error` indicated that you dont have appropriate JNI or native .so files in proper place

The .so files has to go under app->JniLibs->.so files.

Comment: Appreciate your reply. I do not have the JniLibs folder under my app folder/main project, so do I create one? Also, where can I get the .so file from?

Comment: @DonovanTan did my answer helped?

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

The problem lies in the libs folder not being in my tess-two folder. (libs folder should originally be inside tess-two, I previously removed it for another purpose)

"libpngt.so" should be located in:
 -> libraries -> tess-two -> libs -> armeabi-v7a -> libpngt.so

Thanks for all the responses so far, cheers :)